# How to save data like value and key?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want to build an app to report revenues and expenses.
And I want to keep data like how much money comes in, when and how.
And build structured categories like 1 cola = -1.5 $ and the like. And when I close the app and restart the cell phone, the data is still saved. I'm only a beginner developer so I got stuck in the step of keeping data

And now what I'm trying to do is use SharedPreferences to save the budget, and then print it in TextView. And it does not work.

MY ACTIVITY:

```
public class Report extends AppCompatActivity {

Button mButton1;
EditText mEdit;
TextView mText;
Button mButton;

SharedPreferences menaPref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;


public static final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "My Money";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_report);

    mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.B_GetMoney);
    mEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.T_InputMoney);
    mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    mButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.B_try);


    mButton.setOnClickListener(


            new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String value = mEdit.getText().toString();
                    ;


                    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

                    editor.putString("My Money", value);
                    String Show_My_Money = pref.getString("My Money", null);

                    mText.setText(Show_My_Money);


                }

            });

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class PrefHelper

```
public class PrefHelper{

private static final String PREF_NAME = "my_pref";

public static final String MY_MONEY= "my_money";
// put your others key here


Preferences() {
}

public static void writeBoolean(Context context, String key, boolean value) {
    getEditor(context).putBoolean(key, value).commit();

}

public static boolean readBoolean(Context context, String key) {
    return getPreferences(context).getBoolean(key, false);
}

public static void writeString(Context context, String key, String value) {
    getEditor(context).putString(key, value).commit();
}

public static String readString(Context context, String key) {
    return getPreferences(context).getString(key, null);
}


private static SharedPreferences getPreferences(Context context) {
    return context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

private static SharedPreferences.Editor getEditor(Context context) {
    return getPreferences(context).edit();
}
}
```

and just for read and write use these methods

```
// for write data
PrefHelper.writeString(getApplicationContext(), PrefHelper.MY_MONEY, "500 $");

// for read data
String money = PrefHelper.readString(getApplicationContext(), PrefHelper.MY_MONEY);
```

Comment: thanx, you know maybe how am i could to build report like: time: 1:30 am Category: Food

Answer (score 0):

You need to `.commit()` or `.apply()` the changes made to the editor first after you put something in it.

```
editor.putString("My Money", value);
editor.commit()
pref.getString("My Money", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use commit() or apply() to save your data ;)

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

                editor.putString("My Money", value);
                editor.commit();
```

Refer to this documentation:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html